# regex repeated asterisk pattern matching

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

If I do the regex matching

```
preg_match('/^[*]{2}((?:[^*]|[*][^*]*[*])+?)[*]{2}(?![*]{2})/s', "**A** **B**", $matches);
```

I get the result for `$matches` I want of

```
Array ( [0] => **A** [1] => A )
```

but I am not sure how to modify the regex to yield the same result in `$matches` from the input text without the space in the middle, that is, `"**A****B**"`.

Comment: examples of the string(s) your matching against and the desired results would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the regex matching

```
preg_match('/^[*]{2}((?:[^*]|[*][^*]*[*])+?)[*]{2}/s', "**A****B**", $matches);
```

yields the result for `$matches` I want of

```
Array ( [0] => **A** [1] => A )
```